# How to get certificate for Azure Automation Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-automation

I need to create automaion client for Azure webhook.

Following code is written by me to get AutomationManagementClient Value.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertBase64String"]));

  var creds[![enter image description here][1]][1] = new CertificateCloudCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionId"], cert);

  AutomationManagementClient automationManagementClient = new AutomationManagementClient(creds);
```

I need that  certificate string i.e. **CertBase64String** value as I don't know from where I will get that value.
Help me...

This error I am getting after updating as per your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create the automation client, I suggest you try to use the ARM way to operate the automation. The following is the demo code works correctly on my side.

**Prepare:** Registry an AD application and assign role to applcation, more details please refer to Azure official [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). After that we can get tenantId, appId, secretKey from the Azure Portal.

We could use the following code to get the token

```
 var tenantId = "tenantId";
 var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
 var clientId = "application Id";
 var clientSecret = "client secret";
 var resourceGroup = "resource group";
 var automationAccount = "automationAccount";
 var subscriptionId = "susbscriptionId";
 var token = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                "https://management.azure.com/",
                new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret)).Result.AccessToken;
```

if you use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation/2.0.4) Version <= 2.0.4 please try the following code.

```
  var automationClient = new AutomationManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId,token));
  var webhook = automationClient.Webhooks.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, automationAccount,new WebhookCreateOrUpdateParameters
                {
                   Properties =  new WebhookCreateOrUpdateProperties
                   {
                       ExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
                       IsEnabled = false,
                       Parameters = parameters,
                       Runbook = new RunbookAssociationProperty
                       {
                           Name = "xxxx"
                       },
                       Name = "xxxx",
                       Uri = "https://xxxx.xx"

                   } 
                });
```

if use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation Version 3.0.0-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation/3.0.0-preview), please try to the following case.

```
 var automationClient = new AutomationClient(new TokenCredentials(token)) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId};
 var webhook = automationClient.Webhook.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, automationAccount, "webhookName",
  new WebhookCreateOrUpdateParameters
   {
      ExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
      IsEnabled = false,
      Parameters = parameters,
      Name = "xxxxx",
      Runbook = new RunbookAssociationProperty
      {
           Name = "xxxxx"
      },
      Uri = "https://xxx.xxx"


  });
```

**Update:**

You could set the **Parameters = null** or if you have parameter, you could define the parameters as dictionary. Please also add the **Name = "xxxx"** in the code.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"test", "test"}};

var webhook = automationClient.Webhooks.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, automationAccount,new WebhookCreateOrUpdateParameters
                {
                   Properties =  new WebhookCreateOrUpdateProperties
                   {
                       ExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
                       IsEnabled = false,
                       Parameters = parameters,
                       Runbook = new RunbookAssociationProperty
                       {
                           Name = "xxxx"
                       },
                       Name = "xxxx",
                       Uri = "https://xxxx.xx"

                   } 
                });
```

I test it on my side, it works correctly

[image]

Comment: I have run above code but I got error at "parameters" as "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: parameters.Name'"

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation  are you using and which line get the error? You could add the detail information about that.

Comment: You could set the Parameters = null or if you have parameter, you could define the parameters as dictionary. I also update the answer, details please refer to it.

Comment: I am still getting same error. I have updated my question as I  have added snap of error. Please check it and help me

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I also add the webhook name.  `Name = "xxxx"`

Comment: Yes error has gone but I added that "Name" attribute beside "Properties" attribute

Answer (score 0):

"CertBase64String" will get by passing thumb-print of that certificate to following fucntion.

```
internal static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromthumbPrint(String certThumbPrint) {
  X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

  certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  //Find the certificate that matches the thumbprint.
  X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbPrint, false);
  certStore.Close();

  //Get the first cert with the thumbprint
  X509Certificate2 cert = (certCollection.Count > 0) ? certCollection[0] : null;
  return cert;
}
```